Meaning of isabelle clarsimp/fastforce's background turning light red
Image to fastforce with light red background

This keeps happening in my proofs. As you can see, the proof goal window is blank. What does the light red background on fastforce mean? The same happends with clarsimp.
It seems to hang forever once that happens.

Can't post image because stackoverflow thinks there's too little text

Is there any additional output when you position the caret on the fastforce call? If yes, that will probably tell you what the problem is.
But my guess is that there is none, and in that case the problem is usually that the fastforce call diverges and eventually runs out of memory and crashes. That is usually the cause of lines in Isabelle being printed in red like this. This can have a number of reasons: excessive backtracking, a simplifier loop, etc.

No there is no additional output. I've uploaded another image of clarsimp failing the same way with the cursor on clarsimp. And by putting a using [[simp_trace]] before the clarsimp, I saw I indeed have a rewrite loop (and it stops crashing in that case, it just runs forever). Thanks!

You have to be really careful with what kind of rules you declare as simp because debugging simplifier loops is very annoying. Until you get the hang of it it is better to err on the side of caution and only add them if they look absolutely safe.
